# How to access the appDataFolder with the DriveApp or the Drive Service of app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I was thinking this might work:

`var ADF = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFoldersByName('appDataFolder');`

I also tried:

`var ADF = Drive.Children.list('appfolder');`

But I get: "The current scope does not allow use of the appdata folder"

The Drive Service v.2 is enabled both in the script resources and on the Developer's console. Version 3.0 is not listed is not available in the Resources dialogue box.

Is this folder accessible to stand-alone app script webapps at all?

I would like to store my webapp data files there, rather than creating a visible folder on the user's root.

Comment: Call `googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=<yourtoken> ` and see if `drive.appdata` is listed. Looks like it's not authorised properly. You should also be able to see it from the Google Script editor if that is where your code is.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue? I am looking for the same...

Comment: Unfortunately, No. I tried all the proposed solutions, but none worked.

Answer (score 1):

**Is this folder accessible to stand-alone app script webapps at all?**

It is possible, using the right [scope](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/appdata) to access it.

> Get authorization to use the Application Data folder
>
> - To be able to use your Application Data folder, request access to the following scope:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata
```

### How To's

[**Check Scopes in project**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)

- `File -> Project Properties -> Scopes`
  [image]

To add scopes, you must create a [OAuth2 for Apps Script](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2), here is a github sample of a Google Apps Script library to access the [Appfolder](https://github.com/Spencer-Easton/Apps-Script-Appfolder-Library) in Google Drive.

**Switch On the Google Advance Service**

- `Resources -> Advance Google Services....` 
  [image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: v3 doesn't show up on the Resource list. Only v2 is available which is turned on. It is also enabled in the API console. The scope tab displays the ones that this script has access to but features no "add/edit/create" button. So how to add the scope?

Comment: It is under the File Menu -> Project Properties then scope, you can add the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata` scope there

Comment: I find the scopes tab. But there no way no add anything there. There's just save and cancel. No way to edit the list. No add button. No input / form field to fill. It only says the project requires 3 OAuth scopes. How do you actually do it?

Comment: Folks - thanks so much for the question, response and especially the example. That's a little painful for both the user and the implementor, though -- seems like Google could make this all quite easy by implicitly adding that scope to the project via a new helper method that returns a Folder for the appDataFolder only. I added a feature request here, please up vote if you concur. https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6592

Comment: ...and I just discovered my request was likely a dup of https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4840, which I'd recommend upvoting as well (or instead) of 6592. Thanks and sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

During Google sign in, add  the `app data scope`  to your list of sign in scopes.